# Compare Key ID of RPM package with Key Fingerprint of RPM-GPG-KEY

Tags: rpm, gpg, key-authentication

During work with RPM packages I frequently need to validate signatures against available GPG keys.

Using

```
rpm -qip --nosignature <package.rpm> | grep Signature
```

gives me an Key ID, i.e.:

```
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Mon 28. Aug 2019 06:00:00 AM CET, Key ID 1234567890abcdef
```

whereby

```
gpg --with-fingerprint <RPM-GPG-KEY-package>
```

gives me a Key Fingerprint:

```
Key fingerprint = 0987 6543 21FE DCBA 0987 6543 21FE 1234 5678 90AB CDEF
```

Since it is not easy to compare both outputs, how to get the mentioned Key ID instead of the whole fingerprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[During research I've found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115180/266568) that the Key ID are usually the last 8 or 16 bytes of the Key Fingerprint. So I wanted to extract just them from the output. How to achieve that?

I've found the following approach which seems to be working:

**keyID.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

KEY_PATH=$1
KEY_FINGERPRINT=$(gpg --with-fingerprint ${KEY_PATH} | grep "Key fingerprint" | cut -d "=" -f 2 | tr -d ' ' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

echo ${KEY_FINGERPRINT} | grep -o '.\{8\}$'
echo ${KEY_FINGERPRINT} | grep -o '.\{16\}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the GPG key using `rpm --import GPGFILE` and then run `rpmkeys --checksig foo.rpm`