# What are the keyid and finguerprint of a public key in gpg and apt-key?

Tags: gpg, apt-key

https://superuser.com/a/931814/ says

> Here follows an example command to use the GnuPG package's `gpg` command
> to receive a key (`-recv-keys`) with the fingerprint `7CE8FC69BE118222`:
>
> ```
> $ gpg --recv-keys 7CE8FC69BE118222
> ```

Are a key and its fingerprint different concepts?

From manpage of `apt-key`:

> `apt-key export <keyid>`
>
> Output the key `keyid` to standard output.

Are a key and its `keyid` different concepts?

Are the `keyid` and fingerprint of a key the same concept?

For example, we can first retrieve the key with

```shell
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

and then feed it to `apt-key` with

```shell
gpg -a --export E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Is `E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9` a key, the `keyid` of a key, or the fingerprint of a key?

Why does it still work if I replace `E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9` with `51716619E084DAB9`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GnuPG : representations of key IDs and fingerprints](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115174/gnupg-representations-of-key-ids-and-fingerprints)

Comment: I am not sure. I am still unclear about my questions

Comment: What do a key, its key id, and its fingerprint look like?

Answer (score 7):

The answers to [GnuPG : representations of key IDs and fingerprints](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115174/86440) explain the differences between key ids and fingerprints. Key ids and fingerprints are (parts of) hashes of keys, so they are different from keys.

Let’s take one of my public keys as an example; a minimal export in binary format is just under 4KiB in length, and that’s the whole key (without its signatures). That’s rather unwieldy, so my key is identified by its fingerprint:

```
7196 E081 94D5 3FCB FD15  D960 FA6C 71F9 A73D BE0B
```

That’s a reliable identifier for my key.

Key ids are shorter; the “long” key id is

```
0xFA6C71F9A73DBE0B
```

(the last eight bytes of the fingerprint), and the “short” key id is

```
0xA73DBE0B
```

Neither of these should be used for key identification nowadays — it is possible to create keys with matching key ids (and this has been demonstrated with short key ids).